# How to calculate the percentage of data points belonging to a range of values?

Tags: r

Given a table of values (say between 0 to 100) and the attached plot, what would be the simplest way using R to calculate how many of the data points fall between values 20 - 60 (the red box in the image)?

And is there a way to create that red box using R's plotting functions (I did it using a image editor...)?

Thanks for the help.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To calculate the probability mass contained within the interval:

```
x <- rnorm(1e6)  ## data forming your empirical distribution
ll <- -1.96      ## lower bound of interval of interest
ul <- 1.96       ## upper bound of interval of interest

sum(x > ll & x < ul)/length(x)
# [1] 0.949735
```

---

And then to plot the histogram and the red box:

```
h <- hist(x, breaks=100, plot=FALSE)       # Calculate but don't plot histogram
maxct <- max(h$counts)                     # Extract height of the tallest bar
## Or, if you want the height of the tallest bar within the interval
# start <- findInterval(ll, h$breaks)
# end   <- findInterval(ul, h$breaks)
# maxct <- max(h$counts[start:end])

plot(h, ylim=c(0, 1.05*maxct), col="blue") # Plot, leaving a bit of space up top

rect(xleft = ll, ybottom = -0.02*maxct,    # Add box extending a bit above
     xright = ul, ytop = 1.02*maxct,       # and a bit below the bars
     border = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: @mrdwab -- Thanks. I had missed that, thinking that it was just a very well illustrated question, I guess!

Comment: You could calculate maxct for the interval and not the whole histogram.

Comment: @Roland -- OK. Just added a fix for that as well. Done with this now.

Answer (score 8):

```
set.seed(42) 
x <- rlnorm(5000) #some data
hist(x) #histogram
rect(7,-50,10,100,border="red") #red rectangle
table(cut(x,breaks=c(0,7,10,Inf)))/length(x) #fraction of values in intervals
#(0,7]    (7,10]   (10,Inf] 
#0.9754   0.0136   0.0110
```

`Cut` categorizes the values according to which interval they belong in. `table` then creates a table of counts, which then can be divided by the total count `length(x)`.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: I disagree. I commented the code and everything else can be found using R's excellent help system.

Comment: I think something in between might have been useful here, which is the point Martijn makes. You stand greater chance of getting +1's that way.

Comment: This is great, only problem I am having is that I needed to switch length(x) with nrow(x). Not sure if it is related but for some reason the values returned by the cut/length do not sum to 1.

Comment: @user971956 Well, if you contributed any [reproducible code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we could tailor the answers to your specific case.

Comment: Roland, I am using the code you have supplied, the only difference is that my data is loaded from a large CSV file into a table, and all values of interest are in column 4...

Comment: @user971956 `x <- df[,4]`, where df is your data.frame.

Comment: Found why it doesn't sum to 1, some of the values are equal to 0, so the first parameter in the breaks needs to be equal to -Inf. Thank you very much for your help.